# segmentation vault when using malloc to create a dynamic 2D array, consisting of enums

Tags: multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, malloc, ncurses, dynamic-arrays

First of all, im no english native so writing something like this is difficult for me and I'm new here. Hi :)

I am using Linux Mint on a virtual machine and gcc. I am using curses. I have been trying to fix this error for hours ;(

1.) this is my enum:

```
// Codes on the board
enum BoardCodes {
    BC_FREE_CELL = 1,    // Cell is free
    BC_USED_BY_WORM = 2, // Cell occupied by worm
    BC_FOOD_1 = 3,       // Food type 1; if hit by worm -> bonus of type 1
    BC_FOOD_2 = 4,       // Food type 2; if hit by worm -> bonus of type 2
    BC_FOOD_3 = 5,       // Food type 3; if hit by worm -> bonus of type 3
    BC_BARRIER = 6,       // A barrier; if hit by worm -> game over
};
```

2.) this is the cells variable, inside my struct "worm":

```
enum BoardCodes **cells;
```

3.) and this is how i want to create the array:

```
aboard->cells = malloc((aboard->last_row +2)*sizeof(int*));
if(aboard->cells == NULL) {
    showDialog("Abbruch: Zu wenig Speicher","Bitte eine Taste drücken");
    exit(RES_FAILED); // No memory -> direct exit
}   
int y;
for (y = 0; y < aboard->last_row; y++) {
    // Allocate array of columns for each y
    aboard -> cells[y] = malloc((aboard->last_col + 2)*sizeof(int));
    if((aboard -> cells[y]) == NULL) {
        showDialog("Abbruch: Zu wenig Speicher. Code2","Bitte eine Taste drücken");
    }   
}
```

inside of the showDialog it says "insufficient memory, press any key"

4.) i debugged it using gdb. The segmentation fault happens here:

```
aboard->cells[y][x]=board_code;

(gdb) print x
$3 = 40
(gdb) print y
$4 = 10
(gdb) print aboard->last_col
$5 = 165
(gdb) print aboard->last_row
$6 = 28
(gdb) print board_code
$7 = BC_BARRIER
```

5.) i was trying to print the values of the array:

```
(gdb) print aboard->cells[1][1]
$9 = 3087007176
(gdb) print aboard->cells[1][2]
$10 = 3251580
```

but they should be BC_FREE_CELL:

```
void fillwithfreebcs(struct board* aboard)
{
    int y=0;
    int x=0;
    //fill board and screen buffer with empty cels
    for (y = 0; y < aboard->last_row; y ++) 
    {   
        for(x = 0; x < aboard->last_col ; x++ ) { 
              aboard->cells[y][x] = BC_FREE_CELL;
              //placeItem(aboard,y,x,BC_FREE_CELL,SYMBOL_FREE_CELL,COLP_FREE_CELL);
        }   
    }
}
```

thank you so much :)

(when i used enum Boardcodes* instead of int* there was the same error message.)

rgds, Tobi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry

the code with malloc was never executed because of a return that i forgot to delete...

haha